# T-SQL - NOEXEC & NOPARSE server wide command or connection/session based?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I was wondering when I run a command such as

```
SET NOPARSE ON
```

or

```
SET NOEXEC ON
```

Does that stop all commands from running? Or only commands within my connection session?

I want to use these for testing syntax/commands remotely first but don't want to run the risk of it blocking other applications from running.

If anyone could shine some light on this it would be fantastic.

Comment: If it was server-wide I don't know how they could ever safely be used... I'm pretty sure they are session-only or even more local.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Transact-SQL programming language provides several SET statements that change the current session handling of specific information.

[SET Statements (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190356)